# How to check dropdown required validity of kendo dropdown in angular 5 app?

Tags: angular5, kendo-dropdown, angular-validation

I am developing my app using angular 5.

I want to validate if the kendo dropdown value is selected other than the default value. How can i do it?

Below is the html code:

```
 <kendo-dropdownlist id="removalReason" name="removalReason" required="required" [data]="followupRemovalReasons"
                            [defaultItem]="defaultItem"
                            [textField]="'value'"
                            [valueField]="'id'"
                            [(ngModel)]="selectedReason">
        </kendo-dropdownlist>
        <span class="font-arial font-13" *ngIf="!ifFollowupReasonSelected" [ngClass]="{'red': !ifFollowupReasonSelected}">Select a reason</span>
```

And in my angular component, i am checking the value of "ifFollowupReasonSelected".
if "ifFollowupReasonSelected" is false, then the text in  is displayed. 
Code from angular component:

```
public defaultItem: { id: number, value: string } = { id: 0, value: "Select item..." };
  public selectedReason;
  ifFollowupReasonSelected = true;
```

I want the kendo dropdown to be highlighted in red, when i submit the form and the dropdown still has default value. How can i do the angular/kendo way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you find the answer to your question?

Comment: Were you able to find a solution with the telerik documentation?

Answer (score 0):

On [this](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/editing/custom-reactive-editing/) page of the telerik documentation you can find a proposal on how to achive this when working with a kendo-popup and reactive Form. Although you are not working with a reactive Form I think this approach can be used when directly binding to a model.
[image]